# How to check some value and enum with linq (both parameters)?

Tags: c#, linq

```
 public enum RoleEnum
    {
        Manager = 1,
        Employee = 2
    }


public void CreateEmployee()
        {
           
            Console.WriteLine("This operation can be handle ONLY by Manager!!!");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Id");
            var userManagerId = Console.ReadLine();
            CheckManagerById(userManagerId);

            if (userManagerId != null)
            {      
           
            }
                    
         }

        private  Employee CheckManagerById(string ManagerId)
        {
            
            return _employers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ManagerId);
        }
```

Manage functionalities can only be used by managers. (Ask for user Id and check if it is a manager).
How can I check both parameters only by Id with linq?

Or how can I go on?

Comment: you have some major disconnect here `private  Employee CheckManagerById(string ManagerId)  {    return _employers....` you expect n `Employee` but look in `Employer`

Comment: How does your data model represent whether the person with a given ID is a manager? Is there an `IsManager` property on `Employee`? An `EmployeeType` enum, as your title hints at?

Comment: Your `CheckManagerById` only returns the first employee with the matching id. How exactly do you determine if an `Employee` is a manager? Do they have a `RoleEnum` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be too early to answer this since there's missing information, but it appears to me that you want to filter employees based on both the `Id` and their `Role`. If that's the case, then you could do something like:

```
private Employee GetManager(string employeeId)
{
    return _employees.FirstOrDefault(employee => 
        employee.Id == employeeId && 
        employee.Role == RoleEnum.Manager);
}
```

Then in your other method, you check the return value from this method. If it's `null`, then either the employee id wasn't found, or the specified employee isn't a manager:

```
public void CreateEmployee()
{
    Console.WriteLine("This operation can be handle ONLY by Manager!!!");
    Console.Write("Please enter your Id: ");
    var userId = Console.ReadLine();

    Employee manager = GetManager(userId);

    if (manager != null)
    {      
        // employee is a manager and may continue
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't need the `Employee` object, but just need to know if the provided `Id` is a valid manager id, you could write a method that returns `true` if an employee with that id is a manager using the `Any` method, which returns `true` if any objects in the collection meet the criteria:

```
private bool IsManager(string employeeId)
{
    return _employees.Any(employee => 
        employee.Id == employeeId && 
        employee.Role == RoleEnum.Manager);
}
```

And then the calling method would look like:

```
public void CreateEmployee()
{
    Console.WriteLine("This operation can be handle ONLY by Manager!!!");
    Console.Write("Please enter your Id: ");
    var userId = Console.ReadLine();

    if (IsManager(userId))
    {      
        // employee is a manager and may continue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Firstly I had an error in RoleEnum class (public Enum RoleEnum {get;set;} instead of (public RoleEnum Role {get;set;} ) and so I could not access that property at all and then I learned a lot from the rest below .I apologize for not sharing more information as a first post :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you're looking for is If the ID of the person supplied is manager, than you can create employee. See comments in code

```cs
public void CreateEmployee()
{
        
    Console.WriteLine("This operation can be handle ONLY by Manager!!!");
badid:
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Id");
    string userManagerId = Console.ReadLine().Trim(); // <-- see this!

    // add this
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userManagerId))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Id. Try7 again");
        goto badid;   
    }
            

    bool isManager = IsManager(userManagerId);

    if (isManager)
    {      
        // Collect employee data here 
        . . . . . .  . . .  .
        // save
        string newId = CreateNewEmployee(.......);
        Console.WriteLine("Employee created. ID: " + newId);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot add new employee. To create employee the requestor must have manager role.");
    }
                    
}

private bool IsManager(string managerId) // <-- change signature
{
    // This is logically correct by I don't know your model property identifier
    var e = _employees  // <-- you have employers here but need employees
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == managerId && x.Role == RoleEnum.Manager);
    return e != null;
}

// need to define
private string CreateNewEmployee(.......) // <-- presumably return new ID. 
{
    . . . . . . . . 
}
```

Now... looking at the title of your question *"How to check some value and enum with linq (both parameters)?"*

This line answers it

```
FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == managerId && x.Role == RoleEnum.Manager);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, dear sir, for your time. From your answer, it became much clearer to me how we can do validations, I even did other validations, such as whether an employee with such an ID first exists in the database. :)